# Z-index not working nested absolutes divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've one question that why `z-index` not working in nested absolutes:

**Here my code:**

```css
.relative {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.absolute {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: #16E186;
  z-index: 4;
}

.absoluteChild {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #1665e1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.absoluteGrandchild {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0056;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
    Hello World
    <div class="absoluteChild">
      <div class="absoluteGrandchild">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The [z-index property is probably one of the most misunderstood properties in CSS. To use it properly, you need to understand the concept of [url=http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking]stacking contexts](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index).

Comment: page not found !!

Comment: try this one https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 2):

> Within a stacking context, child elements are stacked according to the
> same rules previously explained. Importantly, the z-index values of
> its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent. Stacking
> contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent
> stacking context.
>
> ...
>
> Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents
> are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of
> the parent stacking context.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

It works as intentional. They are stacked in the correct order within their parent.

Answer (score 2):

Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.

Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` is a third-dimensional graphical indexing. Imagine a table where lots of papers are present. In this analogy the paper above the other paper has a higher `z-index`. However, you believe you experienced a different behavior, however, you are mistaken. Imagine a closed book on the table. It has a first page, a second page and so on. While you can index the pages of the book, you cannot put any of the pages of the book above or below the book unless you take it out of the book. In more technical terms, `z-index` indexes siblings, but will not index child-parents.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually supposed to work that way.

Let me explain with boxes. Whenever you give a `z-index` value to an element, it becomes a box. Consequently, we have three boxes.

- A big box: `.absoulte`
- A medium box: `.absoluteChild`
- A small box: `.absoluteGrandchild`

You can give an order of how your want the sibling boxes in to be stacked, but you can't say that you want a smaller, child box to be on top of a bigger, parent box.

To the packaging man, aka the browser, you are saying with your z-index values:

- Get a big box and give it the number 4.
- In the big box, get a medium box and give it a number 1.
- In the medium box, get a small box and give it a number 1.

A box with a lower value will go under a box with a higher value of the same size.

### Warning

You must not take a *littler* box and stack it on top or below that of a bigger *box*! What happens in the box stays in the box! Not doing so will cause an unstable stack of boxes that will give all developers a massive headache!

Lastly, you start the sizes of the box from the first time you set a z-index value.

- no value

  - no value

    - no value
    - value (big box)

      - value (medium box)

        - value (small box)
      - value (medium box)

        - value (small box)
        - value (small box)
        - value (small box)
- value (big box)

  - value (medium box)

    - value (small box)
  - value (medium box)

    - value (small box)
    - value (small box)
    - value (small box)